# Exactly how do destructuring assigments in function arguments work?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I don't understand why the destructuring logic in the call of the function is actually declaring a new variable.

```js
function fn() {}
let object = {x: "Ele", y: "From", z: "Stack"};

fn({x} = object);

console.log(x);
```

And secondly, what's the problem in the logic below.  I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`.  However, when I'm using `var` works fine.

```js
function fn() {}
let object = {x: "Ele", y: "From", z: "Stack"};

fn({x} = object);

let x = "Dummy";
console.log(x);
```

I have a lack of knowledge with the previous logics.

Comment: `{x} = object` is a destructing *assignment* that happens *before* the function is called.

Comment: The second error is because of the definition of `let` statements: you cannot refer to the variable before the `let` declaration (unlike `var`).

Comment: @Pointy **good point**, js is a crazy world for desclaring variables while you're actually calling a function.

Comment: @Ele: `{x} = object` doesn't **declare** a variable, it **assigns** to `x`. There are other languages where assignment is an expression, i.e. an assignment can appear wherever an expression can appear. E.g. in C or PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...actually declaring a new variable

It's what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). This line:

```
fn({x} = object);
```

is effectively:

```
({x} = object);
fn(object); // a bit of hand-waving here, but roughly speaking...
```

Since it's assigning to an undeclared variable, it creates a global. If you were using strict mode, you would have gotten a ReferenceError instead:

```js
"use strict";

function fn() {}
let object = {x: "Ele", y: "From", z: "Stack"};

fn({x} = object);

console.log(x);
```

The result of an assignment is the value being assigned. In the case of a destructuring assignment, the value being assigned is the thing being destructured (the value of `object`, in your case).

> ...secondly, what's the problem in the logic below. I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`

The problem when you add `let x` is that the line assigning to `x` is now in the Temporal Dead Zone for the declaration of `x`. `x` is *reserved* at that point, but not initialized. The error message says "not defined" because the `let x` line hasn't been executed yet. As though you had:

```
x = 0;
let x;
```

Comment: @ele it is declared, but not defined :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second question first: You cannot use a variable declared with `let` (`x` in this case) before it was declared. When doing `{ x } =` you do destructure into `x`.

Now when you do `fn({ x } = object)` that is basically a function call with its first argument being an assignment expression, and that always evaluates to the result of the right hand-side. `a=b` evaluates to `b`, `{x} = object` evaluates to `object`.

> I don't understand why the destructuring logic in the call of the function is actually declaring a new variable.

Any assignment to an identifier that was not declared yet does create a global variable implicitly. `"use strict"` mode to prevent that.